# Creating successful combination of sets of from combination table

Tags: python, pandas, set

Good day,

I wish to select two control subjects for each of my selected subjects. I got beginning data like thus:

```
Cohort  Controls
#a      #1
#a      #2
#a      #3
#a      #4

#b      #1
#b      #2

#c      #5
#c      #6
#c      #1
#c      #2
```

I want result table with unique Controls for each Cohort subject like this:

```
#a      #3
#a      #4
#b      #1
#b      #2
#c      #5
#c      #6
```

Here is the catch: There needs to be logic to select controls so that we don't end up in 'dead end': If we select **.groupby('Cohort').head(2)** we select combo A-1 and A-2 leading  leading B without matches.

I solved this via brute force order by random, loop each Cohort, take 2 and drop taken from lists. If less than 2 per Cohort, repeat. This is slow, stupid and unreliable.

How would one go about doing set-magic to 'take two from each set so that each child-set remains unique (and no overlaps)'.

Comment: why do you remove #1/#2 from #a but not #b? Would the other way around be also valid?

Comment: @mozway Because B has only 2 candidates (#1 and #2) -> Final table has to have those two. (And if selection pathway takes any other, the find fails. )

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are many possible combinations for the output.

A simple heuristic (not necessarily optimal) could be to first keep the duplicates in the groups with few values (counted with [`groupby.nunique`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.nunique.html)) by sorting before [`drop_duplicates`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.drop_duplicates.html):

```
num = df.groupby('Cohort')['Controls'].nunique()

out = (
 df.sort_values(by='Cohort', key=num.get)
   .drop_duplicates(subset=['Controls'])
)
```

Output:

```
  Cohort Controls
4     #b       #1
5     #b       #2
2     #a       #3
3     #a       #4
6     #c       #5
7     #c       #6
```

##### more complex heuristic

Here we compute the items that belong to a unique cohort and assign them, then we loop over the remaining items and assign them one by one starting with the cohort with the least number of possible choices and we repeat until done (or stuck).

That's probably not perfect and you would need to use backtracking if you want a solution that works for all edge cases, but it should (hopefully) work in most situations.

```
target = 2

sets1 = df.groupby('Controls')['Cohort'].agg(set)
length = sets1.str.len()
unique = set(sets1[length==1].index)
# {'#3', '#4', '#5', '#6', '#7', '#8'}

sets2 = df.groupby('Cohort')['Controls'].agg(set).to_dict()
# {'#a': {'#1', '#4', '#2', '#3'},
#  '#b': {'#1', '#7', '#2'},
#  '#c': {'#5', '#6', '#1', '#2'},
#  '#d': {'#1', '#8'}}

out = {}
used = set()

sets2 = dict(sorted(sets2.items(), key=lambda x: x[1]))
for k, s in sets2.items():
    # keep up to "target" unique items
    out[k] = {x for i,x in enumerate(s&unique) if i<target}
    used.update(out[k])
    s-=used
    
cont = True
while cont:
    # sorting the cohorts with the least number of remaining choices first
    sets2 = dict(sorted(sets2.items(), key=lambda x: x[1]))
    cont = False
    for k, s in sets2.items():
        if len(out[k]) >= target: # we're done with this key
            continue
        if len(s)>0:
            item = next(iter(s))  # adding one more item
            cont = True
            out[k].add(item)
            used.add(item)
            s -= used
```

Output:

```
{'#a': {'#3', '#4'},
 '#b': {'#1', '#7'},
 '#c': {'#5', '#6'},
 '#d': {'#1', '#8'},
 '#e': {'#10', '#9'}}
```

Used input:

```
   Cohort Controls
0      #a       #1
1      #a       #2
2      #a       #3
3      #a       #4
4      #b       #1
5      #b       #2
6      #b       #7
7      #b      #10
8      #c       #5
9      #c       #6
10     #c       #1
11     #c       #2
12     #c       #9
13     #c      #11
14     #d       #1
15     #d       #8
16     #e       #9
17     #e      #10
```

Comment: Nice. This seems to work, but only when smallest set is restricting. I wonder if there is more analytical path to find this. Something like decision pathway maybe?

Comment: @pinegulf yes, this is not always optimal as stated. I have another idea but this will require a more complex code, I'll make an edit later ;)

Comment: One mere thing: this doesn't take into account the 'take 2' rule. Something like out.groupby('Cohort').head(2) will fix this.

Comment: @pinegulf so you just want 2 items, if you had and extra #7 for #c you would leave it out?

Comment: Any extra would be left out in this specific case. Customer want 2x number of control cases for each cohort person.